# How to look for a parent element which contains a specific selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Let's suppose to have the following html structure (1).
From `$('.child') element` I can access the `$('.gran-parent') element` making something like `$('.child').parent().parent();`.

Anyway I don't think this is a good way because is not generic.
Let's suppose there are other divs between $('.gran-parent') and $('.child').
What is the most generic way to refers to the first parent which class is `gran-parent`, starting from `$('.child')` ?

```
<div class='gran-parent'>
    <div class='parent'>
        <div class='child'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```
$('.child').closest(".grand-parent");
```

`.closest` will keep traversing up until it finds a `.grand-parent`. You can also do `.parents(".grand-parent")` but that could return more than one result, depending on your DOM hierarchy, so you would have to do:

```
.parents(".grand-parent").eq(0)
```

or:

```
.parents(".grand-parent").slice(0)
```

or:

```
.parents(".grand-parent:first")
```

all of which are less elegant than `.closest()`.

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/closest/
- http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) operator.

Example:

```
$('.child').parents('.gran-parent');
```